# Select count on Oracle Query based on distinct condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I am newbie with oracle pl/sql, 
right now using oracle sqldeveloper,

i need help for my homework,

how to make the column number 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ... count based on first value column, the DISTINCT OWNER ?

can anyone help me? or suggest me with some hint?

```
SELECT DISTINCT OWNER as SCHEMA, 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME) FROM DBA_OBJECTS where object_type = 'TABLE') "TABLE",
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME) FROM DBA_OBJECTS where object_type = 'VIEW') "VIEW",
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME) FROM DBA_OBJECTS where object_type = 'MATERIALIZED_VIEW') "MATERIALIZED VIEW",
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME) FROM DBA_OBJECTS where object_type = 'INDEX') "INDEX",
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME) FROM DBA_OBJECTS where object_type = 'SEQUENCE') "SEQUENCE",
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME) FROM DBA_OBJECTS where object_type = 'TYPE') "TYPE",
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME) FROM DBA_OBJECTS where object_type = 'SYNONYM') "SYNONYM",
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME) FROM DBA_OBJECTS where object_type = 'DATABASE LINK') "DATABASE LINK",
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME) FROM DBA_OBJECTS where object_type = 'LOB') "LOB",
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME) FROM DBA_OBJECTS where object_type = 'JOB') "JOB",
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME) FROM DBA_OBJECTS where object_type = 'TRIGGER') "TRIGGER",
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME) FROM DBA_OBJECTS where object_type = 'PROCEDURE') "PROCEDURE",
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME) FROM DBA_OBJECTS where object_type = 'FUNCTION') "FUNCTION",
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME) FROM DBA_OBJECTS where object_type = 'PACKAGE') "PACKAGE",
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME) FROM DBA_OBJECTS where object_type = 'PACKAGE BODY') "PACKAGE BODY"
    FROM DBA_OBJECTS
    WHERE OWNER IN ('BERKAS', 'BIAYAPERJALANAN', 'DASHBOARD', 'DIKLAT', 'FLATKKP', 'INVENT', 
    'KKPWEB', 'KKPWEBAUDITOR', 'KONTEN', 'LP2B', 'LPPB', 'MITRAKERJA', 'MOBILE', 'OLTPUSER', 'ONEDEE', 'PEGAWAI', 'PERENCANAAN', 
    'PETA', 'PM', 'PNBP', 'PNBPTRAIN', 'SIMPEG_1703', 'SIMPEG_2702', 'SIPT', 'SKP', 'SURAT', 'SURATBDG', 'TEMATIK', 'TIMKENDALI', 
    'WEBAPIDATA', 'WILAYAH') ORDER BY OWNER;
```

this is wrong, i need the count n other column based on the first column
what should i do ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use conditional aggregation as following:

```
SELECT OWNER as SCHEMA, 
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN object_type = 'TABLE' THEN 1 END), 0) "TABLE",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN object_type = 'VIEW' THEN 1 END), 0) "VIEW",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN object_type = 'MATERIALIZED_VIEW' THEN 1 END), 0) "MATERIALIZED VIEW",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN object_type = 'INDEX' THEN 1 END), 0) "INDEX",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN object_type = 'SEQUENCE' THEN 1 END), 0) "SEQUENCE",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN object_type = 'TYPE' THEN 1 END), 0) "TYPE",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN object_type = 'SYNONYM' THEN 1 END), 0) "SYNONYM",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN object_type = 'DATABASE LINK' THEN 1 END), 0) "DATABASE LINK",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN object_type = 'LOB' THEN 1 END), 0) "LOB",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN object_type = 'JOB' THEN 1 END), 0) "JOB",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN object_type = 'TRIGGER' THEN 1 END), 0) "TRIGGER",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN object_type = 'PROCEDURE' THEN 1 END), 0) "PROCEDURE",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN object_type = 'FUNCTION' THEN 1 END), 0) "FUNCTION",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN object_type = 'PACKAGE' THEN 1 END), 0) "PACKAGE",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN object_type = 'PACKAGE BODY' THEN 1 END), 0) "PACKAGE BODY"
    FROM DBA_OBJECTS
    WHERE OWNER IN ('BERKAS', 'BIAYAPERJALANAN', 'DASHBOARD', 'DIKLAT', 'FLATKKP', 'INVENT', 
    'KKPWEB', 'KKPWEBAUDITOR', 'KONTEN', 'LP2B', 'LPPB', 'MITRAKERJA', 'MOBILE', 'OLTPUSER', 'ONEDEE', 'PEGAWAI', 'PERENCANAAN', 
    'PETA', 'PM', 'PNBP', 'PNBPTRAIN', 'SIMPEG_1703', 'SIMPEG_2702', 'SIPT', 'SKP', 'SURAT', 'SURATBDG', 'TEMATIK', 'TIMKENDALI', 
    'WEBAPIDATA', 'WILAYAH') 
    GROUP BY OWNER
    ORDER BY OWNER;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: you add coalesce function too, so the result is not (null) but become 0
thank you for the answer, i learn my lesson

Answer (score 0):

Use a `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT owner AS schema,
         object_name,
         object_type
  FROM   DBA_OBJECTS
  WHERE  OWNER IN (
    'BERKAS', 'BIAYAPERJALANAN', 'DASHBOARD', 'DIKLAT', 'FLATKKP', 'INVENT', 
    'KKPWEB', 'KKPWEBAUDITOR', 'KONTEN', 'LP2B', 'LPPB', 'MITRAKERJA', 'MOBILE',
    'OLTPUSER', 'ONEDEE', 'PEGAWAI', 'PERENCANAAN', 'PETA', 'PM', 'PNBP',
    'PNBPTRAIN', 'SIMPEG_1703', 'SIMPEG_2702', 'SIPT', 'SKP', 'SURAT',
    'SURATBDG', 'TEMATIK', 'TIMKENDALI', 'WEBAPIDATA', 'WILAYAH'
  )
)
PIVOT ( COUNT( DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME ) FOR OBJECT_TYPE IN (
  'TABLE' AS "TABLE",
  'VIEW' AS "VIEW",
  'MATERIALIZED_VIEW' AS "MATERIALIZED VIEW",
  'INDEX' AS "INDEX",
  'SEQUENCE' AS "SEQUENCE"
  -- rest of your object types.
) )
ORDER BY schema;
```

Comment: Just curious to know: Why `DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME`?

Comment: @Tejash Because the OP uses `COUNT( DISTINCT object_name )` in their query and i have mimic'd the behaviour as closely as I can. Yes, counting the `DBA_OBJECTS` table there will not be duplicate distinct values (per owner) and that keyword could be dropped but if the OP wants to apply it to a different table where they want to count distinct values then it would be required.

Comment: thank you for the information and the explanation sir @MT0